# SVC scikit predict odd and even numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to predict odd and even numers with a SVC, 
but my output is not what I expect

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
data = np.array([[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]])
label = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])

clf.fit(data, label)
print(clf.predict([[3]]))
print(clf.predict([[4]]))
print(clf.predict([[5]]))
```

results in

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

what did i wrong ? I would expect [3] and [5] to be [0]

I am using:

```
numpy==1.9.1
scikit-learn==0.16.1
scipy==0.13.3
```

Comment: Are you using two identical columns in data array? Really?

Comment: well this was my first try with a svc, I changed the iris sample. I update my code, but the output remains the same. So feel free to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=100)
```

will give the expected

```
clf.predict(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 1))
> array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

You can not generalize outside of the range of the training data with this kernel for this task.
You would need a sinusoidal kernel (not in sklearn) to learn this, I think. Or you could just use a sinus of your features.

Comment: this is over-fitting and not useful for predictions.

Comment: Well, as I said above, the concept "even number" can not be learned with an RBF kernel.

Answer (score 1):

**[update]** 
SVM are not valid for this case of problems. The algorithm can not find a line/plane/hyperplane which separate values with label 0 from  values with label 1.

---

Your data is not linearly separable. 
Try user a kernel like rbf `svm.SVC(kernel='rfb')` maybe it can help you

Comment: rfb is the default one (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html ), svm.SVC(kernel='linear') generates the same output